# Help with identifying characteristics of elements power supply S040SN2400167

Tags: power-supply, passive-components

I've faced with overvoltage issue for my hue lamp.

I found that a power supply(Model:S040SN2400167) of that lamp :
[image]

was burnt a bit: [image]

Could you help with identifying characteristics of elements in red area?

[image]
[image]

ps: was able to make a photo for RT1 element:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

> *Could you help with identifying characteristics of elements in red
> area?*

My best guesses: -

- Fuse, F1 2 amps 250 volt AC rated
- MOV1, metal oxide varistor possibly rated at 275 volts AC
- RT1 - likely to be a negative temperature coefficient thermistor to reduce inrush current

To find equivalent parts, you should use Farnell, RS components, Digikey or Mouser but, there are other likely suppliers in your area.

The RT1 device is going to be the most problematic because it is the least-defined by your pictures so, look for any clues to part numbers written on the device itself but, it's going to have about 1 to 2 ohms resistance when warm and maybe 10 to 20 ohms resistance when cold.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will check that! I also found more information on RT1 and updated my 1st message.

Comment: [Microtherm NTC thermistor](https://datasheetspdf.com/datasheet/SCK-2R55A.html) - it looks like it is 5 ohms at 0 degC falling to around 1 ohm when warmed up @valerii